# Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null error after removing div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please Help:  I'm having a number of issues here.  I'm making a clone of Trello and I've been able to create an input field and add cards.

(1). The first issue is that clicking the ***add card*** button multiple times adds multiple *blank* cards and I only want it to add one card at a time (with the text that the user added)

(2).  When I change the text in the text area it changes the text in the already created card. One card should be created with the user's text, when the user clicks the ***Add a Card*** again he/she should be able to create a new card with different text (not change the text on the same card).  In general, the user should be able to add new cards with different text every time they click on the ***Add a Card*** button.

(3).  The third issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to re-add another ***inputField*** after removing it. When I click on the ***Add another card*** link I get this error message: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null'.

Here is the link to my codepen: https://codepen.io/Joanc/project/editor/ALkRVN

```js
/*** ADD A CARD AND DELETE CARDS ***/

/*** Create and text-area (//for user input)// and add buttons for adding and deleting input***/
function displayInputField() {
  //Add an input field
  var a = document.getElementById("inputField");
  var b = document.createElement("textarea");
  b.setAttribute("type", "text");
  b.setAttribute("id", "userInput");
  b.setAttribute("overflow", "break-word");
  b.setAttribute("placeholder", "Enter a title for this card...");
  a.appendChild(b);

  //Add a "Add a Card" button
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerHTML = "Add Card";
  button.setAttribute("id", "createNewCard");
  a.appendChild(button);

  //Add a button for closing (X) Input
  var closeButton = document.createElement("closeButton");
  closeButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>';
  closeButton.setAttribute("id", "createNewCloseBtn");
  a.appendChild(closeButton);
  createNewCloseBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    removeCard();
  });

  //Call the CreateCard function to create a new card after click.
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    createACard();
  });
}

//Hide the "Add a Card" link after click it.
function hideButton() {
  document.getElementById("addCardLink").style.visibility = "hidden"; // hide the button
}

//Creates a new card
function createACard() {
  var createCardElem = document.getElementById("createCard");
  var createNewCard = document.createElement("div");
  createNewCard.setAttribute("id", "newCard");
  createCardElem.appendChild(createNewCard);
  var inputTaker = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
  document.getElementById('newCard').innerHTML = inputTaker;
}

/** ADD A CARD **/

//removes the inputField and buttons from the document and shows the 'addAnotherCardLink' after it has been clicked.
function removeCard(inputField) {
  var element = document.getElementById("inputField");
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  document.getElementById("addAnotherCardLink").style.display = "block";
  displayInputField();
}

function appendInputToCard() {
  var input = document.getElementById('input');
  var card =document.getElementById('newCard');
  var inputTaker = document.getElementById('input').value;
  document.getElementById('newCard').innerHTML = inputTaker;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(12,57,83);
}

/*** CARD COLUMNS ***/
/*** A temporary card holder ***/
.cardColumns {
  padding-top: 20px;
  max-width: 20%;
  /* height: 300px; */
  background-color: rgb(237, 239, 240);
  border-radius: 3px; /*** for rounded corners ***/
}

.cardColumns h4 {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

/*** CARD ***/

/*** Adding shadows for card effect ***/
.card,
#newCard {
  margin: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.2);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px; /*** for rounded corners ***/
  padding: 1px 20px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 50px; /* REMOVE AFTER YOUVE FIXED CARD */
  font-size: 14px;
}

.card:hover,
#newCard:hover {
  background-color: rgb(248, 249, 249);
}

textarea {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 210px;
  /* width: 84%; */
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.2);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px; /*** for rounded corners ***/
  display: block;
}

.addCardBtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 8px 13px;
  background-color: rgb(90, 172, 68);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.2);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px; /*** for rounded corners ***/
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

button {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 8px 13px;
  background-color: rgb(90, 172, 68);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.2);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px; /*** for rounded corners ***/
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#createNewCloseBtn {
  color: rgb(131, 140, 145);
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

a#addCardLink,
a#addAnotherCardLink {
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(131, 140, 145);
}

a#addCardLink:hover,
a#addAnotherCardLink:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

a#addAnotherCardLink {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie-edge">
  <title></title>

  <!-- Link to CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

  <!-- Link to Font-Awesome 5 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!--Link to google fonts - Roboto and Open sans (400, 400 italics, 700 bold, 700 italics)-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Temporary Card holder - will delete and create a modal -->
  <div class="cardColumns">
    <!-- Temporary heading -->
    <h4>General</h4>
    
    <!-- CARD -->
    
    <!-- Create card here -->
    <div id="createCard"></div>

    <!-- Create text-area and 'Add Card' and close 'X' buttons here -->
   
    <div id="inputField"></div>

    <!--AddCardLink - when clicked it adds an input field, and the buttons for adding a card and closing the input field. -->
    <a id="addCardLink" href="#" onclick="displayInputField(); hideButton();"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add a Card</a>

    <a href="#" onclick="displayInputField()"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add another Card</a>

  </div>
  <!-- Link to JavaScript -->
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: One thing that I notice about your code is that your adding multiple cards to your HTML which have the same `id`. `id`s should be unique to each element. Consider using a `class` instead.

Comment: I tested your code. There is no issue for number 1, it functions properly. For the second issue rename "createNewCloseBtn" to "closeButton" since you have created it but for handing event you have used the `id` name which is wrong. Your third issue is not clear to me. Do you want to remove **userInput** or **inputField**?

Comment: @ShakibaMoshiri Thank you for your help.  I want to re-add the **inputField** when the user clicks the **Add another card** link because it would have already been removed when the user clicked the close button (**X**). I want to provide the option to add it again.

Comment: Where is `addAnotherCardLink` element? you have not created it, have you? it has this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null` when tries to run this line: `document.getElementById("addAnotherCardLink").style.display = "block";`

Comment: @ShakibaMoshiri Should I create a different function for it? I thought I was creating a new card when I called the **displayInputField()** onclick.

Comment: @ShakibaMoshiri What I'm doing is calling a function that creates it **displayInputField()**.  This function is called when you click the **Add a card** link, then that link disappears and the **inputField** appears (which has a **Add a Card _button_ and a close **X** button). When you click the **X** button the  **inputField** disappears and the **Add another card** link appears.  This is where I'm having the issue, I want to re-add the **inputField** and I do this by calling the **displayInputField()** function when I click the **Add another card** link but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because at first you have added `HTML` statically there is no error when you call **displayInputField()** for the first time. But for the second one since you have deleted it and there is no `div#inputFiled` you should check it out:

```
var a = document.getElementById("inputField");
var inputFieldExist = true;
// null means we do not have div#inputField in our DOM so we should create it
if (a === null) {
    a = document.createElement("inputField");
    a.id = "inputField";
    // so we need to add this newly created element to our DOM
    inputFieldExist = false;
}
// var b = document.createElement("input");
var b = document.createElement("textarea");
...
...
```

second in this part:

```
closeButton.setAttribute("id", "createNewCloseBtn");
a.appendChild(closeButton);
// we do not have "createNewCloseBtn"
createNewCloseBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    removeCard();
});
```

you have added a listener on `createNewCloseBtn` which is the **id** of `closedButton`. So it should be:

```
closeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    removeCard();
});
```

Also at the end we should add newly created `inputField` to our DOM if it did no exist:

```
if (!inputFieldExist) {
    document.querySelector('div.cardColumns').appendChild(a);
}
closeButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    removeCard();
});
```

and the last thing you need is removing/commenting the `displayInputField()` function to prevent duplication

```
function removeCard(inputField) {
    var element = document.getElementById("inputField");
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    document.getElementById("addAnotherCardLink").style.display = "block";
    //displayInputField();

    // showButton();
    //   document.body.appendChild(element);
}
```

here is the result: https://codepen.io/k-five/project/editor/XMMJGk

Comment: WOW! This is so helpful and very well explained.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @Joan. You are welcome. If it solved your problem please mark it as accepted and here is why: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @Shakira Moshiri I sure will. Thanks again.